# SQL update table1 with condition in table2?

Tags: sql, postgresql

SQL update table1 with condition in table1?

```
table1:
  id_x
  field

table2:
  id
  id_x
  type_id;


update table1 set field=2 where type_id = 4;
```

How can I do that(PSQL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for you, assuming `id_x` in table2 is foreign key reference of `id_x` in table1 -

```
update table1 set field=2
where id_x in 
(
   select id_x from table2 where type_id = 4
)
```